# can not check whether a table exists or not in postgresql

Tags: sql, c, database, postgresql, libpq

I'm writing a C program that connects to a postgreql db.I'm trying to check for a table :

```
PGresult  *re=PQexec(connection, "SELECT to_regclass('fp_stores_data')");
```

this variable is a global variable. but when I compile the code this error occurs:

```
db.c:6:20: error: initializer element is not constant
6 | PGresult const *re=PQexec(connection, "SELECT to_regclass('fp_stores_data')");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a global variable, C requires that it be initialized with something known at *compile time*; if it requires a call to `PQexec()`, this is a *runtime* thing and not allowed (as your compiler has told you).

If the variable needs to remain global, best is to initialize the `re` variable to NULL, and move the actual `PQexec()` call/assignment into runtime code just after the database connection has been established.

A non-database example: you cannot initialize any static variable with a runtime call, so:

```
FILE *infile = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");  // NO

int main()
{
    infile = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");    // YES
    ...
```

It's ok for the *variable* to be static; it's only the *assignment* that must be made at runtime.

Alternatively, if the variable is *local*, it can be initialized with a runtime call.